# How to filter out some packets in a pcap file, based on their host dst ip?

Tags: linux, networking, pcap, tcpdump

I am trying that:

```
$ zcat my_pcap.gz | /usr/sbin/tcpdump -r - -nn host dst 161.15.215.20
reading from file -, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
tcpdump: syntax error
```

Why is the reason for the syntax error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents say "dst" should precede "host"

[Link](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html)